# Chrome starts running in background after startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, google-chrome

- Run chrome in backgroud: unchecked/disabled
- task scheduler: no process at all (not even google update tasks)
- msconfig: checked, there is no active item related to google.
- extensions: disabled but nothing changed.
- anti-virus scan: done but nothing found.

But chrome is still running in background after startup. When I run chrome by myself, those extra processes are still there. When I close those extra ones, it doesnt effect my browser (browser is not closing, extentions are fine). I wouldn't mind if it isn't draining my cpu power but it is draining it. It literally slows my computer down. Also heats my computer up ofc.

Task manager screenshots:

[image]

It slows my computer especially when I play games. Sometimes I forget to close those processes and for example run gta v, fps is really low, computer gets too hot..When I kill those processes, everything works better. I don't know why this is happening. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a solution, but I couldn't find anything. If anyone else is having the same problem, here is my solution.

I created a ".bat" file that contains command below:

```
Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
```

After saving bat file, you need to create a shortcut of it and move that shortcut into startup folder. Here is how to reach startup folder:

Run <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> prompt:

```
shell:startup
```

Answer (score 0):

To completely stop Chrome, go to your System Tray in the bottom right corner of the screen.  (You may need to click the up arrow to see the Chrome icon.)  Right-click on the Chrome icon and click on "Exit" to stop all Chrome processes.  You can also click on "Let Chrome run in background" to disable/un-check that option.

I haven't tested if this change lasts after a reboot, but you can always stop Chrome completely this way.

Comment: Like i said in my post, that option is already unchecked. And I dont see chrome icon in system tray. I know most of these stuffs. There has to be another problem. I tried all these basic things. None of them worked. The other reason why I posted this is, I wanted to see if anyone else is having the same problem? if not, it has to be related to my pc. Maybe I need to install windows again..

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was delete all tasks (update) from control panel>Task Scheduler>*

When Update runs, Windows defender use lot of resource (cpu) for scan the compressed files.

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly why this happens. There is a VBE script which runs Chrome and navigates to `hxxp://www.google.com.487382835812038.windows-display-service.com/` (replaced `http` with `hxxp` to avoid accidental clicking) in headless mode every time you boot your computer and that script itself runs because its listed in the **Run** key in the registry.

To stop this you have to delete the registry value of the script by pressing Ctrl+R on your keyboard then type regedit, navigate to this key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and delete the value called **Windows Updates Service** or you can just open your explorer and type **%appdata%** in the navigation bar then hit enter, you should find a folder called **Windows Updates Files** that contains the script. Delete the whole folder and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

One way to remove that from automatically running in background in startup is to Open Task Manager -> Startup and see if Chrome is present there. If it is, just right click and select disable

Comment: well it was the first thing i did, but there is nothing about chrome